# Probability Function From the k-th Moment

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

If there exist Moment-Generating Function of $X$, $k$-th moment $m_k$ is

$$m_k = \sum_{0\le l \le k}\dfrac{k!}{(k-2l)!l!}2^k, \;k=0,1,2... \; \text{and }l\in\Bbb N$$

Then I need to find Probability function of $X$

I had derived $m_1 = 2$, $m_2 = 12$, but these are not helpful.

Any hint?

Comment: Is there any information about $X$?

Comment: no. that's all I got

Comment: What is the Moment-Generating Function in your question? Is $M(t)=\mathbb E e^{tX}$ right?

Comment: correct. I need to infer the exact pdf from above info

Comment: Why you don't take $X=0$ to get the contradiction?

Comment: Ok, the information is lacked in your first version. Now it seems better.

Comment: Sorry for the before ambiguity. I had not included info in title into the OP

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the typo $0\leqslant\ell\leqslant k$ by the correct condition $0\leqslant2\ell\leqslant k$ in the summation that defines each $m_k$, one gets
$$
E(e^{tX})
=
\sum_{k\geqslant0}m_k\frac{t^k}{k!}
=
\sum_{k\geqslant2\ell\geqslant0}\frac{(2t)^k}{(k-2\ell)!\ell!}
=
\sum_{\ell\geqslant0}\frac{((2t)^2)^\ell}{\ell!}\sum_{k\geqslant2\ell}\frac{(2t)^{k-2\ell}}{(k-2\ell)!}
=
e^{(2t)^2}\cdot e^{2t}
$$ 
which you should be able to recognize as the MGF of a well known distribution.